# Missing icons in Software Updater Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, updates, icons, update-manager

See image for a one-look explanation:

[Software Updater with missing icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVRZV.png)

As the image shows, I'm missing the 'cardboard box' icons from the Software Updater. I know that they are supposed to be their from another machine that runs 18.04, but on this machine with the same OS, the icons are missing.

See this image to illustrate the missing icon:

[Image from the internet with cardboard box icon](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/software-updater-in-raring.jpg)

So now my question to you: What causes this? Is it important? How can I fix this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what is wrong in your screenshot.

Comment: Looks like you are using a custom theme. Check your icon theme. Also: What flavor of Ubuntu are you running? Upgraded or fresh installation?